# iOS13 UISearchController doesn't follow pull down

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

The same code, when running on iOS12, the search bar follows the pull down, but iOS13, it seems to stick to the header. This causes the refresh animation to overlap the search controller.

How to get it to follow the pull down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems fixed in iOS 13.1. No changes in code needed.